Fixed-point theorem and ability to access its own source code
I am reading this text about quines and, it mentions a fixed-point theorem in computability (which I believe is Rogers's fixed-point theorem).
Just after that, it says:

The fixed-point theorem has other amusing applications. Essentially, its intuitive (and effective) content is that a program may use its own source as a variable, i.e. adding to a programming language the ability for a program to manipulate itself (its source code) does not add to its expressive power.

While I understand how the fixed-point theorem proves the existences of a quine (consider a fixed-point of the function $F$ that takes a program and prints its source), I fail to understand precisely how it relates to the quote above.
What kind of computable function $F$ should I consider and how to deduce that a program may have access to its own source code (or something along these lines)?

This is more obvious from the formulation of Kleene's second recursion theorem.

@NaïmFavier Oh I should have read that Wiki page entirely before asking :)
